# $F$ is proper if and only if $\operatorname{deg}(f)=\operatorname{deg}(g)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f, g \in C[z]$ be two non constant monic polynomials.
Consider the homotopy function $F:[0,1] \times C \rightarrow C$
$$
F(t, z)=(1-t) f(z)+\operatorname{tg}(z)
$$
Show that $F$ is proper if and only if $\operatorname{deg}(f)=\operatorname{deg}(g)$.

$\Leftarrow$ is easy because then $F(t, z)=z^{n}$ for some $n \geq 1$ and it is proper, first it is continuous and for every bounded set, its preimage under $z^{n}$ is bounded because $|z|^{n} \geq|z|$.

About $\Rightarrow$ I need to find a compact set in codomain that its compactness cannot preserved under the homotopy map. First of all since it is continuous closedness will be preserved but I need to find the compact set such that its boundedness should not be preserved.
WLOG assume $n>m$ and let $f=z^{n}, g=z^{m}$ then $F(t, z)=z^{m}\left((1-t) z^{n-m}+t\right)$
I think that finding some patologies with $\epsilon>0$ after analysing the following
Take $B[0, \epsilon] \subset \mathbb{C}$
Then
$$
F^{-1}(B[0, \epsilon])=\left\{(t, z) \in[0,1] \times \mathbb{C}:\left|(1-t) z^{n}+t z^{m}\right| \leq \epsilon\right\}
$$
Stuck here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\deg f=n > \deg g$ and assume that $F$ is proper so there is $Q>0, F^{-1}(|z| \le 1) \subset [0,1] \times \overline {B(0, Q)}$ or equivalently $|F(t,z)| > 1, |z| >Q, 0 \le t \le 1$

Then let $a_0, b_0$ the free terms of $f,g$ and notice that $ta_0+(1-t)b_0, 0 \le t \le 1$ is the segment joining them in the complex plane (could be degenerate if $a_0=b_0$) so in particular for any $|w| \le 1$ that is not on the segment, we have $|w-ta_0-(1-t)b_0| \ge c(w)>0, 0 \le t \le 1$

Pick a fixed such $w$ and then for fixed $0 <t \le 1$ the polynomial $tf+(1-t)g-w$ has leading coefficient $t$ and free term at least $c=c(w)$ in absolute value so by the usual formulas the product of its $n$ roots is at least $c/t$ in absolute value, so for (at least) one root $|z_t| \ge (c/t)^{1/n} \to \infty, t \to 0^{+}$

In particular, if we pick $t$ small enough, we get $|z_t| >2Q$ and $F(t,z_t)=w, |w| \le 1$ contradicting the above, so we are done!

Comment: There is typo taking inverse, 

$Q>0, F^{-1}(t,|z| \le 1|) \subset (|z| \le Q)$

Comment: yes, you are right - the inverse of the unit disc is included in a compact of the product space which is included in the given product